# WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR when invoking CXF client with WSS interceptor from JBoss 5.1.0GA

Tags: xml, jboss, cxf, wss

I have CXF web service client with WSS interceptor that works from console, but when run from JBoss throws exception like that:

Unexpected exception occured

```
Unexpected exception occured 
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: A node is
used in a different document
than the one that created
it.    
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:156)   
at $Proxy1020.getAccountStatements(Unknown Source)  
at com.sru.statement.impl.cs.CSStatementGetter.getStatementFromBank(CSStatementGetter.java:164)   
at com.sru.statement.impl.cs.CSStatementGetter.getStatement(CSStatementGetter.java:90)   
at com.sru.hub.common.statement.CommonStatementImportExecutor.execute(CommonStatementImportExecutor.java:89)   
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)   
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)   
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)   
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)   
(...)
at org.jboss.util.threadpool.BasicTaskWrapper.run(BasicTaskWrapper.java:260)   
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)   
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)   
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)   
Caused by: org.w3c.dom.DOMException: WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: A
node is used in a
different document than the one
that created it.  
at org.apache.xerces.dom.ParentNode.internalInsertBefore(Unknown Source)  
at org.apache.xerces.dom.ParentNode.insertBefore(Unknown Source)  
at org.apache.xerces.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.insertBefore(Unknown Source)  
at org.apache.xerces.dom.NodeImpl.appendChild(Unknown Source)  
at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.SOAPDocument.appendChild(SOAPDocument.java:222)   
at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.SOAPPartImpl.appendChild(SOAPPartImpl.java:297)   
at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.W3CDOMStreamWriter.setChild(W3CDOMStreamWriter.java:119)   
at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.W3CDOMStreamWriter.newChild(W3CDOMStreamWriter.java:109)   
at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.W3CDOMStreamWriter.writeStartElement(W3CDOMStreamWriter.java:137)   
at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor.writeSoapEnvelopeStart(SoapOutInterceptor.java:122)   
at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor.handleMessage(SoapOutInterceptor.java:81)   
at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor.handleMessage(SoapOutInterceptor.java:61)   
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)   
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:531)   
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:462)   
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:365)   
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:318)   
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:95)   
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:134)   
... 80 more
```

It works with those libraries:

```
/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws/2.4.2/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.4.2.jar
/org/apache/cxf/cxf-api/2.4.2/cxf-api-2.4.2.jar
/org/apache/cxf/cxf-common-utilities/2.4.2/cxf-common-utilities-2.4.2.jar
/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-core/2.4.2/cxf-rt-core-2.4.2.jar
/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-simple/2.4.2/cxf-rt-frontend-simple-2.4.2.jar
/wsdl4j/wsdl4j/1.6.2/wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar
/org/apache/ws/xmlschema/xmlschema-core/2.0/xmlschema-core-2.0.jar
/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-bindings-soap/2.4.2/cxf-rt-bindings-soap-2.4.2.jar
/org/apache/cxf/cxf-tools-common/2.4.2/cxf-tools-common-2.4.2.jar
/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb/2.4.2/cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-2.4.2.jar
/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-ws-addr/2.4.2/cxf-rt-ws-addr-2.4.2.jar
/org/apache/neethi/neethi/3.0.1/neethi-3.0.1.jar
/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-ws-security/2.4.2/cxf-rt-ws-security-2.4.2.jar
/org/apache/ws/security/wss4j/1.6.2/wss4j-1.6.2.jar
/commons-logging/commons-logging-api/1.1/commons-logging-api-1.1.jar
/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-transports-http/2.4.2/cxf-rt-transports-http-2.4.2.jar
/org/apache/xmlsec/1.4.2/xmlsec-1.4.2.jar
/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar
```

If client is invoked without WSS interceptor, everything works ok.

WSS interceptor code:

```
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
Endpoint cxfEndpoint = client.getEndpoint();
Map<String, Object> outProps = new HashMap<String, Object>();
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, WSHandlerConstants.USERNAME_TOKEN);
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PASSWORD_TYPE, WSConstants.PW_TEXT);
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.USER, "username_alex");
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ADD_UT_ELEMENTS, WSConstants.NONCE_LN + " " +WSConstants.CREATED_LN);
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_REF, this);
WSS4JOutInterceptor wssOut = new WSS4JOutInterceptor(outProps);
cxfEndpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(wssOut);
```

Any ideas what happen here?

Update:

Some additional hints. I hope it would be helpful:

1. I tried to run the application on Tomcat. It works,
2. Because of this ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-4612?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel I tested the application with two additional versions of CXF: 2.5.7 and 2.5.8. It failed.
3. In /lib/endorsed of my JBoss I have two implementations of SAAJ: axis-saaj.jar and jboss-native-saaj.jar. I tried to combine those libraries and spotted that without both of them the application hand out when processing web service with WSS (application works but nothing happened: there's not error both in the browser and logs),
4. I tried also to add axis-saaj and jboss-native-saaj (separately) to the application's WAR file. The result is similar to point 3.: application hands.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this issue is still relevant or not, but I came across this question when I faced this problem on JBoss 6.1.0. So I thought I will post a solution.

JBoss sets up the defaults for a number of factories involved during the creation and processing of a SOAP message. The one in particular creating the problem here is `javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory`.

Apache CXF has an interceptor called `SAAJOutInterceptor`. This is hard coded in `org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor`.

I am not sure, but I think the idea here is to change the SOAP Message from CXF specific object into a platform specific object. While doing so the MessageFactory initialized is `org.jboss.ws.core.soap.MessageFactoryImpl`. This class comes from the jar `common/lib/jbossws-native-core.jar`.

One brute force solution would be to get rid of this jar. It didn't create any problems in our application. But a more decent solution will be to override the JBoss MessageFactory by defining a file in this exact structure `META-INF/services/javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory` on your application's classpath.

For a WAR file, it has to be put under WEB-INF/classes. This file has a single line as follows:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl
```

Restart the JBoss process after making this change. Hope this works for everyone.